# Given 2 strings, get array of all separate substring phrases greater than x in length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say we have an array of strings:

```
["carflam fizz peanut butter", "fizz foo", "carflam foo peanut butter"]
```

The output of function `get_array_of_substrings_larger_than(min)`, with `get_array_of_substrings_larger_than(3)`, should be `["peanut butter", "carflam", "fizz"]`, because there are at least 2 strings share each of those elements.

I can't quite figure out how to write this.  Note, that it's not the same as simply comparing every string to the others and taking the largest substring -- in the example above, carflam would always be the SECOND largest substring.

`"peanut butter"` is together because when you compare `"carflam fizz peanut butter"` and `"carflam foo peanut butter"`, the largest common substring is `"peanut butter"`.  The second largest substring is `"carflam"`, both of which should be in the output indepdently, HOWEVER, `"peanut"` and `"butter"` should not be in the output because they are both contained in a larger substring

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the example. There's more than substrings going on here? WHy isn't "fizz" one of the array items?

Comment: And how does peanut butter end up as 1 item?

Comment: your question and output is confusing.please clear what you want.

Comment: @Edward: I think we want *common* substrings, not words here. But the method name is a bit off, and there needs to be an explanation of why "carflam" is an item, but "fizz" is not - both are in at least two array elements, and both meet the constraint of being larger than 3 characters.

Comment: Sorry, "fizz" SHOULD be in the output array.  "peanut butter" is first because it's the largest common substring.  I eddited the OP

Comment: @D-Nice: Thanks for the clarification. What have you tried? Sorting an  array of strings by size is pretty easy: `array.sort_by! { |s| -s.length }` - finding the common sub-strings looks like a challenge though

Comment: why is "peanut butter" together and not seperate?

Comment: "peanut butter" is together because when you compare "carflam fizz peanut butter" and "carflam foo peanut butter", the largest common substring is "peanut butter".  The second largest substring is "carflam", both of which should be in the output, HOWEVER, "peanut" and "butter" should not be in the output because they are both contained in a larger substring

Comment: Another question. Why do "carflam " and "fizz " have spaces removed at the end? Why isn't the trailing space considered part of the substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, I think that to be clear what you're asking for is the largest phrase, for lack of a better word. The largest substrings I see in the example array are actually `"carflam f"` and `" peanut butter"`. And feel free to change the `ary` argument if that's a known quantity in whatever class you're using:

```
def get_array_of_phrases_larger_than(ary, min)
  all = []

  # Ugly, but this will span the range of possible phrases for each item in the
  # array, building them into a one-dimensional array if they meet the minimum
  # length requirements
  ary.each do |phrase|
    words = phrase.split
    last = words.length - 1
    (0..last).each do |from|
      (from..last).each do |to|
        p = words[from..to].join(" ")
        all << p if p.size > min
      end
    end
  end

  # Get a list of all repeated keys
  repeated = all.group_by(&:to_s).select { |_, v| v.size > 1 }
  keys = repeated.keys

  # Get a list of the longest keys, such that we exclude "peanut" and "butter"
  # if "peanut butter" exists
  longest = repeated.select do |key, _|
    keys.select { |k| k.include?(key) }.size == 1
  end

  # Sort in reverse order by length
  longest.keys.sort_by { |k| -k.size }
end

@ary = ["carflam fizz peanut butter", "fizz foo", "carflam foo peanut butter"]

get_array_of_phrases_larger_than @ary, 3
# => ["peanut butter", "carflam", "fizz"]
```

Note that this would be agnostic to where the strings come from, so you could potentially have a false positive with something like `["butter butter", "foo", "baz"]` returning `["butter"]`, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `get_array_of_substrings_larger_than(3)` also need to output `fizz` as it is longer than 3 and it is in 2 of the strings?

To solve this you could compare the strings pairwise and find the longest common subsequence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

To find the second longest common subsequence you can remove the longest common subsequence from your strings and so if you found `peanut butter`, the new strings to compare are `"carflam fizz"` and `"carflam foo"`.

Comment: if you have a question, add a comment, not a answer

Answer (score 0):

start here:

```
    a = ["carflam fizz peanut butter", "fizz foo", "carflam foo peanut butter"]

    phrases = {}

    index = 0;
    a.each do |s|
      words = s.split(' ')
      len = words.length
      (1..len).each do |phrase_len|
        (0..(len-phrase_len)).each do |start_word|
          if start_word >= 0
            phrase = words[start_word, phrase_len].join(' ')
            if phrases[phrase].nil?
              phrases[phrase] = []
            end
            phrases[phrase] << "(#{index}) #{s}";
          end
        end
      end
      index = index + 1;
    end

    phrases.each_pair do |phrase, indexes|
      puts "found *#{phrase}* of #{indexes.size} elements"
    end
```

this gives you a map from phrase to index in a where this occurred, i'm sure you can make this do what you want
~

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_array_of_phrases_larger_than(s, min)
    arr = []
    s.combination(2).to_a.each do |x;y,z|
    z = x.first.split(' ').select {|el| el.length > min }
    y = x.last.split(' ').select {|el| el.length > min }
        if (z & y).length == 1
             arr << (z & y).join(" ")
        else
            m = (z & y)
            (2..(m.length-1)).to_a.reverse.each do |l|
                m.combination(l).each do |com|
                 break arr << com.join(" "), arr << (m - com).join(" ") if (x.first.include? com.join(" ")) && (x.last.include? com.join(" "))
                end
            end
        end
    end
    p arr
end

s = ["carflam fizz peanut butter", "fizz foo", "carflam foo peanut butter"]
get_array_of_phrases_larger_than(s,2)
get_array_of_phrases_larger_than(s,3)
get_array_of_phrases_larger_than(s,4)
```

***Output:***

```
["fizz", "peanut butter", "carflam", "foo"]
["fizz", "peanut butter", "carflam"]
["peanut butter", "carflam"]
```